# Query a whole graph from starting node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my neo4j-DB I have several independent graphs which are not connected.
There is a Node inside one of these graphs with the label XY_Object having an:

```
<id>: 115
```

Which is connected to several other Nodes with different labels, creating one of these graphs.

Is it possible to fetch this very graph only by that information? I keep trying some similar Queries from SO but apparently I keep applying and modifying them wrong. (I'm only a beginner with Neo4j)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is a spanning tree : https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.path/apoc.path.spanningTree/